# Set background color of nav bar via theme for react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-elements

I'm trying to set the nav bar background color via ThemeProvider for my app. What component should I target to set the styles.

```
    import { ThemeProvider } from "react-native-elements";
    const theme = {
      ListItem: {
        titleStyle: { fontSize: 30, color: "red" },
        subtitleStyle: { color: "#336699", fontStyle: "italic" }
      },
      Header: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        color: "red"
      }
    };
```

App component's Render :

```
render(){
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <AppNavigator />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

The list item styles can be seen but the header background color isn't set. If I change the screen's navigation options, I can set the color manually there. But I want to avoid doing this on every screen.

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: "Title",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: The module you intend to use is a module in the reaction navigation, not in the element. Therefore, there will be no access to style.

Comment: Please refer https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/customization.html#using-the-theme-in-your-own-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this during configuring my navigation. When setting up navigation via React Navigator's createStackNavigator, there's an option called defaultNavigationOptions that you can use to setup the common styling. Relevant code from the class where I setup the stack navigator.

```
//common styling
const defaultNavigationOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#00f"
  },
  headerTintColor: "#fff",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
};

//override the createStackNav 
const createStackNavCustom = screens =>
  createStackNavigator(screens, { defaultNavigationOptions }, config);

//create stacks
const HomeStack = createStackNavCustom({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  AboutEvent: EventDetailsScreen
});

const AboutStack = createStackNavCustom({
  About: AboutScreen,
  Help: HelpScreen
});
```

Docs here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#sharing-common-navigationoptions-across-screens